# Where have all the erections gone?

Tags: etymology, frequency-analysis

I was experimenting with Google's [ngram tool](https://books.google.com/ngrams/), and came upon this curious result:

[image: erection usage frequency, 1800-2000]

My assumption would have been with the more open attitudes towards discussion of sex, usage for "erection" would have gone up.  Yet it has gone down by over a factor of 3 since 1876.  Searching some old period bands (such as 1820-1840), I saw that the primary use for "erection" had been in the context of erecting a building.  However, the current biological meaning existed as well.

My guess is that people are using the building-related "erection" a lot less, to avoid unintended sexual connotations. If so, they substitute some other terminology. Either that or we write a lot less, proportionately, about building than we used to.

I added "hard-on" to the graph, suspecting it was supplanting "erection", but as the graph shows, it is still relatively insignificant. (It began steady ascent around 1958.) I cannot think of another word likely to be used in books that would be supplanting the biological meaning.

BTW, while writing this, I graphed the same ngram, but terminated it at 2016. The slight upward slope has continued steadily since about 1996. It had yet to reach .00040%, though.  This may be illustrating what I expected initially, more open attitudes toward sex.

Comment: Probably to the same place as [Holmes and Watson’s *ejaculations*](http://qi.com/infocloud/sherlock-holmes) have gone to.

Comment: If you remove the hyphen the usage of "hard on" is on the up.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynu4M.png

Comment: I like how you said "experimenting". Anyway, you can use the year-range search links for Google books below the graph. A cursory look suggests that your hunch is right.

Comment: If you look at the [original Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=erection%2Chard-on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cerection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chard%20-%20on%3B%2Cc0), you'll notice two things: there are no matches included for "hard-on" in the "Search in Google Books" results beneath the graph, and the chart bears a banner label reading "Replaced **hard-on** with **hard - on** to match how we processed the books." In short, Ngram is not designed to search for hyphenated words, so it's useless for "hard-on."

Comment: 'arroused' might have switched it's meaning to erection but lost other meanings?  I'm not sure..it's been going down in usage so it doesn't come close to proving anything

Comment: As a title I would have been tempted with "Why are erections falling?" Is the question in your title? I think you may have answered it yourself. Nowadays writers are avoiding "erected" and "erections" for obvious reasons, and as for tiny number of  "hard-on"s , I think you'll find they are being employed elsewhere on the Internet.

Comment: Other words for building a large building are 'under construction', and perhaps 'being developed' (went way way up from the 1800s)

Comment: I found the missing [erections!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+an+erection%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20an%20erection%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - And here’s some more: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+an+erection%2C+his+erection&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20an%20erection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20erection%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Aren't phrases containing "erection" included in the search for "erection" itself? // @Mari-LouA I don't believe I have answered the title's question. An educated guess was made based on limited research and supposition, but not actual knowledge. It seems unlikely that there is not a pay-walled journal article somewhere tracing, say, general words that have acquired very specific meanings over time.  If not, one of you English PhD masters looking for a thesis topic, you now have one! 

Comment: Yes, Ngram includes all the written instances, but you *were* surprised about the low percentage in recent years, and you were particularly curious about *that* usage, weren't you? I think your educated guess was a very good one but for a more authorative voice we need a lexicographer,  or maybe a linguist.

Comment: @SvenYargs:  Google Ngram Viewer seems to be able to handle hyphenated words correctly; [for example](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=camera-ready%2Cmother-in-law%2Cmerry-go-round&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccamera%20-%20ready%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmother%20-%20in%20-%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmerry%20-%20go%20-%20round%3B%2Cc0).  The fact that the “Search in Google Books:” section doesn’t list them just seems to be a bug.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  Searching for “hard on” does a [search for “hard on”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hard%20on%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl), finding things like “critics are hard on Microsoft” and “I saw *Die Hard* on the airplane”.

Comment: @Scott: I don't think either of us knows what the line graphs labeled "mother - in - law," "merry - go - round," and "camera - ready" are tracking, because we can't see any of the instances that the graphs are built on. In any case, the lack of Google Books search results for such words has been a feature of Ngram since at least 2013, when I first used it. As I noted above, the Ngram tool normally displays an automatic notice when a user enters a hyphenated word in the 'Graph these comma-separated phrases' field: "Replaced **xxx-xxx** with **xxx - xxx** to match how we processed the books." …

Comment: … If you understand what it means to replace **xxx-xxx** with **xxx - xxx**, you know more than I do. I suspect that the tool designers' decision to add letter spaces around hyphens is a response to the problem posed by end-of-line word-break hyphens that don't constitute true compound-word hyphenation—but ultimately I have no idea what their thinking on this point was. It's certainly true that if you search for …

Comment: … [_mother in law_,  _merry go round_, and _camera ready_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=camera-ready%2Cmother-in-law%2Cmerry-go-round%2C+camera+ready%2Cmother+in+law%2Cmerry+go+round&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccamera%20-%20ready%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmother%20-%20in%20-%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmerry%20-%20go%20-%20round%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccamera%20ready%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmother%20in%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmerry%20go%20round%3B%2Cc0) (without any hyphens) you’ll get plenty of “Search in Google Books“ results that include …

Comment: … instances of the terms **with** hyphens. 

Another interesting result of that combined Ngram chart is that the lines plotted for "mother - in - law," "merry - go - round," and "camera - ready" dwarf the lines plotted for "mother in law," "merry go round," and "camera ready"—even though the latter include at least some instances of the hyphenated forms. Again, I have no explanation for that result beyond pure speculation. Ngram users are free to trust Ngram results for hyphenated words if they wish, but they aren't free to verify them.

Answer (score 5):

Tom22 should get credit for this answer.  I read his comment awhile ago, but he sounded dismissive of the idea that **aroused** might be picking up the slack. After just now doing several more comparative graphs, I see that he may well have been onto something.

[access interactive graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arousal%2Caroused%2Cerection%2Carouse%2Chard%20on&year_start=1820&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carousal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caroused%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cerection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carouse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chard%20on%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

I thought about including "woody" from Martin Smith's graph. My searches, however, indicate that it is relatively rarely used in a sexual sense. Most results relate to wood itself, or the male name (eg. Woody Harrelson).

- arousal: not significant until around 1950 when it began a significant rise. It began tapering down around 1983, but still maintains more than 2/3 of its peak in 1983.
- arouse: steady, slow decline during most of the 1900s, with a very recent and small up-slope since about 2002
- aroused: huge decline since about 1936, with slight up-slope since about 2002
- erection: peak around 1876, followed by steady decline until 1997. It has been slowly ascending since then.
- hard on: enjoying a slow, almost steady rise since 1820

All the words except **arousal** have more general meanings.  Even "hard on" is most often found in a non-sexual context. (eg, "She worked hard on her job.") Statistics without a known causality can be very misleading. Yet it seems compelling to me that we see the five words together suggest a coalesced sum total of the sexual connotation of erection. What **erection**, **arouse**, and **aroused** may have lost in any sexual connotation sure looks like it has been picked up by **arousal**.  An exception is **hard on**, changing slowly and maybe gaining more sexual connotation over time, without losing any of the non-sexual usage. (**Hardon** and **hard-on** are statistically irrelevant.)

Comment: You did all the work.  I thought I might be on to something but really haven't messed around with the charts enough to do it.  You deserve extra points for all the puns too !

Comment: @Tom22 Heh, except for the question title, I was not intentionally punning. I've been reminded recently that my sense of humor is not shared universally, so my intent here is to play it straight. Still, I suspect there is an inner 12 year-old (i12yo) in all of us that is all too happy to form connections the author did not intend. That is not to say the author's i12yo did not influence the manner in which he spoke.

Comment: I could not help but notice on the graph  that almost all expressions show a slight _rise_ after 2000, approximately around the time of the FDA approval of Viagra. I just ran another ngram comparing _erection_  with _erectile_, as in disfunction, and guess what popped up? A rise in both after 2000.

Comment: [Here is the ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=erection%2Cerectile&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cerection%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Berection%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BErection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cerectile%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Berectile%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BErectile%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @RichF As implied in your answer, this is not and cannot be the history of a single word. Instead, it should feature here as the **history of a meaning,** and then we could more comfortably include all the words that relate to that meaning, and see how they drop and spike through time according to developments.